# c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.threads debugger extension

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

I'm experiencing an exception in the first run of any SOS extension commands when the load by command is use to load the extension. However if I use the load command the exception is not presented. Below is a step through the process I use. can someone explain why this happens and a possible resolution.

```
0:007> .chain
    Extension DLL search Path:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\pri;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\arcade;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Internal_Tools;C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;c:\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin;c:\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin;C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\tools\Other\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HxD;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0;C:\Internal_Tools\PerfView
    Extension DLL chain:
        pde.dll: image 9, 5, 0, 0, API 9.5.0, built Wed Jun 11 16:29:51 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\pde.dll]
        dbghelp: image 6.3.9600.17029, API 6.3.6, built Thu Feb 20 03:04:49 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\dbghelp.dll]
        ext: image 6.3.9600.17029, API 1.0.0, built Thu Feb 20 03:23:22 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\ext.dll]
        wow64exts: image 6.3.9600.16384, API 1.0.0, built Thu Aug 22 00:03:41 2013
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\wow64exts.dll]
        exts: image 6.3.9600.17029, API 1.0.0, built Thu Feb 20 03:12:50 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\exts.dll]
        uext: image 6.3.9600.16384, API 1.0.0, built Thu Aug 22 00:04:09 2013
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\uext.dll]
        ntsdexts: image 6.3.9600.16384, API 1.0.0, built Thu Aug 22 00:04:34 2013
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
    0:007> !bigline
    -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    0:007> .loadby sos clr
    0:007> .chain
    Extension DLL search Path:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\pri;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\arcade;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Internal_Tools;C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;c:\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin;c:\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin;C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\tools\Other\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HxD;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0;C:\Internal_Tools\PerfView
    Extension DLL chain:
        C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos: image 4.0.30319.34209, API 1.0.0, built Fri Apr 11 21:17:38 2014
            [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll]
        pde.dll: image 9, 5, 0, 0, API 9.5.0, built Wed Jun 11 16:29:51 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\pde.dll]
        dbghelp: image 6.3.9600.17029, API 6.3.6, built Thu Feb 20 03:04:49 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\dbghelp.dll]
        ext: image 6.3.9600.17029, API 1.0.0, built Thu Feb 20 03:23:22 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\ext.dll]
        wow64exts: image 6.3.9600.16384, API 1.0.0, built Thu Aug 22 00:03:41 2013
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\wow64exts.dll]
        exts: image 6.3.9600.17029, API 1.0.0, built Thu Feb 20 03:12:50 2014
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\exts.dll]
        uext: image 6.3.9600.16384, API 1.0.0, built Thu Aug 22 00:04:09 2013
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\winext\uext.dll]
        ntsdexts: image 6.3.9600.16384, API 1.0.0, built Thu Aug 22 00:04:34 2013
            [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
    0:007> !line
    -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    0:007> !threads
    c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.threads debugger extension.
          PC: 728b7713  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000
    0:007> !line
    -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    0:007> !threads
    ThreadCount:      5
    UnstartedThread:  0
    BackgroundThread: 2
    PendingThread:    0
    DeadThread:       2
    Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                             Lock  
           ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
       0    1  ed0 00819228     2a020 Preemptive  00D22AB4:00000000 007e1498 0     MTA 
       2    2  f24 007ea7e8     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 007e1498 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
    XXXX    3    0 0085d748     30820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 007e1498 0     Ukn 
    XXXX    4    0 0085f558   1039820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 007e1498 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
       5    6  c84 00861730   8029220 Preemptive  00E6C270:00000000 007e1498 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 

0:007> lm v m clr
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
71aa0000 7213d000   clr        (deferred)             
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Image name: clr.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Fri Apr 11 21:25:50 2014 (5348961E)
    CheckSum:         0069CE03
    ImageSize:        0069D000
    File version:     4.0.30319.34209
    Product version:  4.0.30319.34209
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® .NET Framework
    InternalName:     clr.dll
    OriginalFilename: clr.dll
    ProductVersion:   4.0.30319.34209
    FileVersion:      4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    PrivateBuild:     DDBLD354
    FileDescription:  Microsoft .NET Runtime Common Language Runtime - WorkStation
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    Comments:         Flavor=Retail
```

Comment: Do you get the exception if the pde.dll extension is not loaded?

Comment: @MarcSherman the exception is generated when the pde extension is not loaded.

Comment: Clearly this is a bug in WinDbg, sos.dll or any other extensions loaded that might have corrupted memory space used by sos.dll. I suggest contacting Microsoft support, only they can investigate the issue.

Comment: I've seen this before. SOS contains a global variable g_ExtControl which it tries to access in GetCMDOption, but it is still null causing this error. Can you show us the output of lm v m clr? I suspect that the version of CLR and SOS do not match. Try grabbing SOS from the machine where the dump was taken and manually loading it with .load instead of .loadby.

Comment: @Dono lm vm clr added

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in DbgEng.dll. A [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3377) was added for CoreClr. Not sure if it ever made its way to the full Framework. You can work around the issue by adding the extension to sos: hence `.loadby sos.dll clr` rather than `.loadby sos clr`.

See [here](http://www.andreybazhan.com/windbg-access-violation-exception-0xc0000005-when-running-the-clrstack-command.html) for full details on the bug.